# Need to check if an event is already happened then exit the (endless) loop but the program must run continously

Tags: python, function, loops, if-statement, schedule

I'm trying to write a little program in Python to search some specific value inside a table on a webpage. Eventually I can get the value with a function called `Alert_Red`. I need to call the function automatically every 5 seconds but when I try the code below it gives me the correct values but in an endless loop.

```
[...some code above...]

def Alert_Red():
    if advColor == avc_red and delta <= fivesec_datetime:
        print('New RED advisory please check the following link: ', link)
        if advColor1 == avc_red and adv_datetime1 == adv_datetime:
            print('Another new RED advisory please check the following link: ', link)

schedule.every(5).seconds.do(Alert_Red)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Output with the first "if clause" true:

```
New RED advisory please check the following link: , link
New RED advisory please check the following link: , link
New RED advisory please check the following link: , link
[endless loop every 5 sec]
```

Output with the second "if clause" true:

```
Another new RED advisory please check the following link: , link
Another new RED advisory please check the following link: , link
Another new RED advisory please check the following link: , link
[endless loop every 5 sec]
```

The program must run continously (even when the if clauses are true because i need to check them always) but I need to be advised only one time (the first time the values are found and/or if they change) and the Output i need is:

```
New RED advisory please check the following link: ', link
```

or for the second "`if` clause" true:

```
Another new RED advisory please check the following link: ', link
```

Comment: It's extremely unclear what the variables your `if` statements mean, and how they get set. Presumably the solution to your repetition problem is to unset them somehow, after you print the first time. But without more information about them I'm not sure how likely it is that we can help you with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your problem, it can be solved with a global variable that tracks whether or not you have issued an advisory.  Initialize this variable to False outside this function (somewhere in your start-up code).

```
def Alert_Red():
    global advised
    if advColor == avc_red and delta <= fivesec_datetime:
        if not advised:
            print('New RED advisory please check the following link:', link)
            advised = True
        if advColor1 == avc_red and adv_datetime1 == adv_datetime:
            if not advised:
                print('Another new RED advisory please check the following link: ', link)               
                advised = True
```